# Else part in not getting execute in perl

Tags: perl

I am not able to figure out why the `else` part is not getting executed:

```
opendir (DIR_03, "$dir_01"."/"."$dir_02"."/"."$file");
@ANR=readdir(DIR_03);
close(DIR_03);
foreach my $anr_file (@ANR) { 
    chomp($anr_file);
    if( $anr_file ne "traces.txt" || 
        $anr_file ne "traces_system.txt" || 
        $anr_file ne "traces_SystemServer_WDT.txt") {
        return("TraceFileNotFound");
    } else {
        return("TraceFileFound");
    }
}
```

Comment: You should work on improving your indentation.

Comment: FYI, `"$dir_01"."/"."$dir_02"."/"."$file"` is better written `"$dir_01/$dir_02/$file"`.

Answer (score 3):

```
if($anr_file ne "traces.txt" || $anr_file ne "traces_system.txt" || $anr_file ne "traces_SystemServer_WDT.txt")
if($anr_file ne "traces.txt" && $anr_file ne "traces_system.txt" && $anr_file ne "traces_SystemServer_WDT.txt")
```

General rule: **Not-equal - or - combinations almost always are wrong.**

(Here if one `ne` is false (equality), the others are guanteed to be true, hence all is true; always.)

Comment: and (from the example given anyway), it's probably more readably written as `if ($anr_file eq "traces.txt" || $anr_file eq "traces_system.txt" || $anr_file eq "traces_SystemServer_WDT.txt") { # file found... } else { # file not found }`

Comment: ...and if not found, shouldn't it proceed to the next file in the directory rather than return, breaking out of the loop? The whole thing looks a little confused

Answer (score 1):

It will always be true because you are using not equals with or.

Simplify it to files `a`, `b`, and `c` and look at the logic.

If the query `$file = 'a'` and you have

```
if ($file ne 'a' || $file ne 'b' || $file ne 'c') {...}
```

you have

```
if (false || true || true) {...}
```

Which is always true, for any value of `$file`. Try changing your logic to `eq`, and changing the contents of the `if-else` blocks accordingly.

```
   if($anr_file eq "traces.txt" || $anr_file eq "traces_system.txt" || $anr_file eq "traces_SystemServer_WDT.txt")
   {
     # Found it!
   }
   else 
   {
     # Not Found
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

This:

```
 if($anr_file ne "traces.txt" || $anr_file ne "traces_system.txt" ...
```

is almost certainly not what you want. If `$anr_file` equals `traces.txt` then it doesn't equal `traces_system.txt`, and so your first clause will always resolve to true.